# Owl Carousel 2 not working on resize window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, owl-carousel

I am using Owl carousel 2 in my page and I want to have the Stage padding option like here:
http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/stagepadding.html

Here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="owl-carousel">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
 </div>
```

my css:

```
 .item {
   background-image: url("myimage.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
   height: 10rem;
 }
```

and my js:

```
 var owloptions = {
    stagePadding: 50,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav: true,
    dots: false,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:2
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
}

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel(owloptions);
```

My problem is that responsive is not working. It works only on reload the page, but not while resizing. And I am wondering if something is wrong on the css or on js? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
       responsive: {
              0: {
                items: 1,
                nav: true
              },
              600: {
                items: 3,
                nav: false
              },
              1000: {
                items: 5,
                nav: true,
                loop: false,
                margin: 20
              }
            }
```

Try this on document ready

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even worst I think.

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work fine, but owl carousel debounces the window resize. So, if you are testing by resizing your browser window, make sure you stop long enough for the carousel to readjust. If that doesn't do it, I'd set the `responsiveBaseElement` and see if that makes a difference. More [here](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/responsive.html).